# Convert physical path to web path asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, path

I need to display an Image in web page. But the Image doesn't exist in the Web directory. If the image is under web directory I know that just "../Images/TN/my.jpg" will work. But the image is available in "D:\Images\TN\my.jpg" and My web site is deployed in "C:\apps\mywebsite".

How do I convert the "D:\Images\TN\my.jpg" path to a relative path so that the Image will be visible in web page?

Comment: Short answer: You cant. That would be one large gaping security hole.

Comment: @leppie Ye! But I wasn't able to figure out what would be security hole here? Web application and the Images folder are in same server then why was this not allowed?

Comment: Think about what happens if the 'hacker' can go to `../../../foo`.

Answer (score 3):

You cant show images if they are not in a virtual directory.
Try holding then in your application folder itself or if its not feasible then  make your Folder holding the image as a virtual directory in the IIS and mount it in your application folder.

Here's what you need to do (way i prefer),

1. Open IIS manager.
2. In Connections under Sites Select your Website and RightClick on it.
3. Select `Add Virtual Directory`... from the Context menu.
4. In The dialogue box that opens Enter the Alias name of your choice like **`"GlobalImages"`**
5. Browse the physical path of the Folder you want to and Select it and Click OK.

You will have it available for **relative url** in that website. like

**www.example.com/GlobalImages**

When you set that in IIS, it is automatically added to your Solution's Project.

Here is the MSDN link if you want..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751432.aspx

Comment: Can you point me to the URL that has step by step process for the second option?

Comment: This should be mark as answer. Thanks @Shekhar_Pro :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is probably set up a [handler](http://www.aspcode.net/Creating-an-ASHX-handler-in-ASPNET.aspx) and use the generic image name. While local, point to the D:. While on the server, point to the web path. (At least so long as you're not keeping them within the virtual directory that is).

Answer (score 0):

TO fetch this point, we always write the absolute directory for images or other resource.But if the resource in the web server, i use the relative directory.